# Adding the curly braces in begning and end of output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have command that gives me following output:

```
'First' : 'abc',
'Second' :'xyz',
'Third' :'lmn'
```

Requirement here is to convert this output into valid json format.
So I replaced all ' to " using sed :

```
<command> | sed "s/'/\"/g"
"First" : "abc",
"Second" :"xyz",
"Third" :"lmn"
```

Now I also need to add { in the begining and end of the output how can I do that.

Any other thoughts are also welcome.

Comment: Can't you use `awk` like `echo "'First' : 'abc' 'Second' :'xyz' 'Third' :'lmn'" | sed "s/'/\"/g" | awk '{print "{" $0 "}"}'` where `echo` in this case is a substitute for your `<command>`?

Comment: Download and use  [`fixjson`](https://github.com/rhysd/fixjson).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -z "s/[[:space:]]*'\([^']*\)'[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*'\([^']*\)'[[:space:]]*/"'"\1":"\2",/g; s/,$//; s/^/{/; s/$/}/'
```

- First match the `'<this>' : '<and this>'`
- Then convert each such sequences into `"<this>":"<and this>",`
- Remove trailing comma.
- Add `{` `}` in front of it.
- `-z` is a GNU extension to parse it all as one line. Alternatively you could remove newlines before passing to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

|sed -e '1s/^/{/' -e "s/'/"/g" -e '$s/$/}/' does the work.

Comment: The result will not be a valid json format. (You need to put a comma between elements.)